# Команды компилятора gcc

Tags: g++, компилятор

Почему-то при команде "g++ -c code.cpp -o r.exe" приложение на выходе не работает. Да и сам файл если открыть блокнотом, то там судя по всему не то, что должно быть на самом деле. + размер файла явно не тот, который должен быть у приложения.

если пользоваться этой командой "g++ -s code.cpp", то на выходе будет рабочий полноценный исполняемый файл.

Вопрос в том, что может ту команду нужно дополнить (которая -c -o) и тогда будет работать?. Может там линковать еще надо и еще что нибудь. Второй вариант рабочий, но правильный ли? Документацию читал, но не вкурил походу еще.

Как правильно вообще это должно быть? Некоторые целые makeфайлы пишут еще. Может и мне стоит? =) Многие предлагают использовать IDE, а я же уже наоборот - хочу слезть с IDE=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Документацию читал

Проверим?

> при команде "g++ -c code.cpp -o r.exe" приложение на выходе не работает

И не должно:

> -c Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link

Дальше,

> если пользоваться этой командой "g++ -S code.cpp", то на выходе будет рабочий полноценный исполняемый файл.

Да не может быть :)

> -S Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.

Ну никак "рабочего исполняемого файла" тут не получить.

> Вопрос в том, что может ту команду нужно дополнить (которая -c -o) и тогда будет работать?

Вопрос в другом. Указанные ключи делают ровно то, что и должны делать, но вам это, судя по всему, не нужно. Так что нужно-то? Просто собрать исполняемый файл из исходника? Вуаля (как и написано в документации):

```
g++ code.cpp -o r.exe
```

Comment: mingw32-g++ -s ura.cpp -Wall -ansi На выходе получил файл a.exe; Не знаю, что за магия.

Comment: g++ code.cpp -o r.exe - Да. Понял. Спасибо. Не знаю зачем я пытался -c добавлять=)

Comment: @Taranga, не вводите в заблуждение. В вопросе указан ключ `-S`, а не `-s`, это совсем разные ключи. Ключ `-s`  заставляет линкер использовать статическую линковку, что, видимо, в вашем случае прокатывает. Читайте документацию, в ней всё есть.

Comment: =) Хорошо. Ошибся. Извините.